# Can Not Change Settings Once Configured MS Edge Using Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, microsoft-edge

Configured MS Edge to use IE Mode following these steps:

1. Install `msedge.admx` administrative template for Microsoft Edge.
   See [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/configure-microsoft-edge).
2. Navigate to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Edge`, enable **Configure
   Internet Explorer integration**, and set option to "Internet Explorer mode".
   See [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#enable-internet-explorer-integration-using-group-policy).
3. Navigate to `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Edge`,
   enable **Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List**, and set option to the path
   of XML file that manage the sites, say `file:///C:/Users/UserA/Downloads/site-list1.xml`.
   See [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy).

The IE mode worked for the sites listed on XML file. Then I want to change the XML file to another path. So I changed the **Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List** setting Using Group Policy editor to a new value, say `file:///C:/Users/UserA/Somefolder/site-list2.xml`. I restarted Edge (even the PC), and the new path just not reflected. **Checked the `edge://policy`, policy value for `InternetExplorerIntegrationSiteList` remained `file:///C:/Users/UserA/Downloads/site-list1.xml`**.

I also tried these:

- Disable the **Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List**, the value in `edge://policy` not change.
- Delete XML file `file:///C:/Users/UserA/Downloads/site-list1.xml`, the IE mode still works.

System Information:

- MS Edge: Version 87.0.664.66 (Official build) (64-bit)
- OS: Windows 10 1909

Comment: You should be able to use [this](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) to identify the registry key and to see if the key is being updated. It’s also possible that the policy no longer is applicable to 1909 and/or Edge 87

Answer (score 0):

It seems that editing using group policy will not cause values in registry being changed. Found the [registry key](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#internetexplorerintegrationsitelist) in `SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\InternetExplorerIntegrationSiteList` and edit its value solved my problem.